# pg-promise multi-row update with geom and json columns

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

I love [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) but am having difficulty inserting multiple rows into a table that has both geom and json columns. I'm not sure of the syntax.

I want to be able to pass in an array of objects for example:

```
[{pt_title: 'title1', 
       lat: -42.360061, 
       lng: -71.065567, 
 waypoints:[[42.360061,-71.065567],[42.360061,-71.06549]]},
{pt_title: 'title2', 
       lat: -43.360061, 
       lng: -71.065567, 
 waypoints:[[43.360061,-71.065567],[42.360061,-71.06549]]}]
```

and update my table points:

```
pt_title varchar,
pt_geom geom,
waypoints json
```

I therefore have to convert the lat and lng values like so:

```
ST_GeomFromText(POINT(${pt.lng} ${pt.lat}), 4326)
```

and also convert the waypoints array into json before updating.

```
CAST(pt.waypoints AS json)
```

I read about using the update helper, but couldn't find any examples of gis columns.  I can't figure how to do the column set so that it knows about the conversion?

Also, is there a helper utility so I can see the resulting SQL string when 
using `db.none(sql, values)` syntax?  I'd like to see what the final SQL is with the values inserted so I can see what's going on.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you? If it did, then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure how to do the column set so that it knows about the conversion?

Property `init` in each [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) is your conversion callback.

Here's your full [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) object:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'pt_title',
    {
        name: 'pt_geom',
        mod: ':raw',
        init: c => pgp.as.format('ST_GeomFromText(POINT(${lng}, ${lat}), 4326)', c.source)
    },
    'waypoints:json'
], {table: 'my-table'});
```

> Also, is there a helper utility so I can see the resulting SQL string...?

See [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), or just handle event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query).

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user2928231 added ;)

Comment: vitaly-t: using columnSet I get this query generated: 

 insert into "walk_points"("walk_id","pt_type","sort","pt_title","dir_text","address","pt_geom","pt_descr") values(131,'intro',0,'','','6504 E Camino Vista',ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-117.76247262954713, 33.83789459593196), 4326),'') RETURNING id, sort, walk_id;

When I console.log that and then paste it into my pg-admin it runs fine.  But when I run it from a transaction I get 
TypeError: Invalid query format.

Comment: @user2928231 this doesn't add up. Can you show the full transaction code?

Comment: I think it has to do with the empty array I'm passing in as a json field.  Is there a special way to handle a json field if there's no data yet? I'd really rather these fields have null if empty.

Comment: An empty array is translated into a valid json.

Comment: So I tried a zillion combos and this is finally what works in my update ColumnSet:
  {
          name: 'waypoints',
          mod: ':raw',
          init: c => pgp.as.format('CAST(${waypoints} as json)', c.source)
      },